# Does XMPP framework store imageData or URL into in build database?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xmpp

Here i am able to fetch text message from core data, but not able to find any received images url or NSData into database
Can anyone help me out for how to fetch images from XMPP inbuild database 
here it my code to fetch text message from core data, thanks

```
func fetchMessageConversation()  {

    // Initialize Fetch Request

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()

    let managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.mainThreadManagedObjectContext

    // Create Entity Description
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject", in: managedObjectContext!)

     // Create predicate //

    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "bareJidStr like %@", bareJidStr)
    fetchRequest.predicate = resultPredicate

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    var resultAry : NSArray!

    do {
    resultAry = try managedObjectContext?.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray!
    //print(result as Any)


    for i in 0..<resultAry.count {

        let messageDetails = resultAry.object(at: i) as? XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject

        if (messageDetails?.body != nil) {

            let composeMsgDic = NSMutableDictionary ()
            composeMsgDic.setValue(messageDetails?.isOutgoing, forKey: "isOutgoing")
            composeMsgDic.setValue(messageDetails?.timestamp, forKey: "time")
            composeMsgDic.setValue(messageDetails?.body, forKey: "message")
            composeMsgDic.setValue(messageDetails?.message.elementID(), forKey: "messageID")
            MsgconversationAry.add(composeMsgDic)

        }



    }

     } catch {

        let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
    }

}
```

Comment: What XMPP framework would that be, exactly?

Comment: Please refer this link you will get idea about XMPP  https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework